# How do I read the metadata information from a closed workbook using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy files from one location to another based upon either the Title or Tags metadata of a file but I cannot seem to be able to do that and I'm not sure why.

This is my code:

```
Path = "C:\Users\blahblah"
destination = "C:\Users\blahblah\blibbityblah"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set obj_folder = FSO.GetFolder(Path)

For Each obj_subfolder In obj_folder.SubFolders
    For Each file In obj_subfolder.FILES
        If InStr(1, file.BuiltInDocumentProperties("title"), "Blah") Then
            Debug.Print file.BuiltInDocumentProperties("title")
            Call FSO.CopyFile(file.Path, FSO.BuildPath(destination, file.Name))
        End If
    Next file
Next obj_subfolder
```

This breaks right here and I get an error message stating that the object doesn't support the property or method:

```
If InStr(1, file.BuiltInDocumentProperties("title"), "Blah") Then
```

Additionally, I've tried using a shell object to identify the tags of the workbook as so:

```
Path = "C:\Users\blahblah"
destination = "C:\Users\blahblah\blibbityblah"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set obj_folder = FSO.GetFolder(Path)
Set shell_object = CreateObject("shell.application")
Set dir_object = shell_object.Namespace(CVar(Path))

For Each obj_subfolder In obj_folder.SubFolders
    For Each file In obj_subfolder.FILES
        If InStr(1, file.Name, ".xlsx") Then
            Debug.Print dir_object.getdetailsof(file, 18)
            'Call FSO.CopyFile(file.Path, FSO.BuildPath(destination, file.Name))
        End If
    Next file
Next obj_subfolder
```

The tag data in my file when I look manually says "Blah" but when I debug.print it only reads as "Tags". Can someone please steer me in the right direction here? Thank you.

**EDIT**

- I have also tried appending `.Value` to the end of the `.BuiltInDocumentsProperties` with the same outcome.
- I have also downloaded and installed the `Dsofile.dll` file and added the reference with the same result.

Comment: `file.BuiltInDocumentProperties("title")` : add `.Value` to that and see if it helps.

Comment: Note: You should ask only one thing / question - this is two things. There's a good chance that no one person may know the answer to both. Please use the [edit] link below the question to remove the second part and post it as a NEW question. That may seem like more work, but you have a better chance of getting quick and thorough answers if you follow the site rules in this respect. If there's more than one topic in a question there's a good chance the question could get closed as "too broad"

Comment: It's [`Workbook.BuiltInDocumentProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties). Emphasis on the `Workbook` portion, which should be an *open* workbook. Not sure at the moment of the solution to the problem, but this should be helpful in explaining the error message.

Comment: @CindyMeister Hi Cindy...thanks for your reply. I have tried appending the .Value to the end already and it hasn't worked. Additionally, I'm not asking two questions here. I was attempting to show what else I have tried. Two different paths to try to get the same result. I was hoping that by showing everything I've tried that it could cancel some things out for when people attempt to help. Thanks.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks...Ok, seeing how "file" in my code isn't set as a workbook (though technically it is), is there a way to pull in either the tag or title information? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example showing how to retrieve details of a file with `Shell.Application`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim oDetails, sName

    Set oDetails = GetDetails("C:\Users\blahblah\blibbityblah\test.xlsx")
    If oDetails.Exists("Tags") Then Debug.Print oDetails("Tags")
    If oDetails.Exists("Title") Then Debug.Print oDetails("Title")
    Debug.Print String(40, "-")
    For Each sName In oDetails
        Debug.Print sName & " = " & oDetails(sName)
    Next

End Sub

Function GetDetails(sPath)

    Dim sFolderName, sFileName, oShell, oFolder, oFile, oDetails, i, sName, sValue

    SplitFullPath sPath, sFolderName, sFileName
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace(sFolderName)
    Set oFile = oFolder.ParseName(sFileName)
    Set oDetails = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 0 To 511
        sName = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFolder.Items, i)
        sValue = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFile, i)
        If sName <> "" And sValue <> "" Then oDetails(sName) = sValue
    Next
    Set GetDetails = oDetails

End Function

Sub SplitFullPath(sPath, sFolderName, sFileName)

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FileExists(sPath) Then Exit Sub
        sFolderName = .GetParentFoldername(sPath)
        sFileName = .GetFileName(sPath)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.

Comment: quick question: Why do you have the for loop in the GetDetails function going until 511?

Comment: @AP1 I just never saw indexes higher than ~300, so decided to use 9 bits, which give such range.